# civiEvents forces patrons fill out the form for every single ticket they buy. Is there something better?

Tags: civievent

I need to be able to have different ticket levels and allow patrons to purchase any number of tickets under *ONE* name/registration. Is there anything in civiCRM that can offer that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [price set](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/complex-event-fees/) with multiple Text / Numeric Quantity fields to allow registrants to specify 8 tickets for one thing and 3 tickets for the other thing.

Here's an example of a price set with Text / Numeric Quantity fields:
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I was kinda thinking that might be my only shot. I have 7 different price levels already. So I guess my only option is to create 35 different levels to allow people to choose between 1 and 5 tickets for each of the 7 levels. 

It's strange. We've been using civiCRM for over 15 years and I don't recall this being the case. Patrons used to be able to just buy as many tickets as they want without individually filling out the form for each guest.

Comment: You don't need to do that! This is exactly what price sets do, I'll add a screenshot to my answer.

Comment: "Patrons used to be able to just buy as many tickets as they want without individually filling out the form for each guest" aren't those old events still be in your system so you can reverse engineer how you set them up.